# Set the cell.backgroundColor using an element from an object in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uicolor

EDIT: Thanx to user2404543, I have found my mistake. Code is edited to show the fix.

I have a tableViewController that sets up a table with a list of states. I am trying to set its cell.background color using a UIColor that is part of an object in an NSMutableArray. The object consists of an NSString stateName, an NSString stateNickName, an NSString licensePlateURL, and a UIColor color. All of the elements of the object populate the table as expected, however, when I try to set the cell.backgroundColor using the "color" element from the object, I get an error. Here is the pertinent code:

The stateObject.h has this information:

```
@interface stateObject : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *stateName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *nickName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *licensePlateURL;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIColor *bkgColor;

-(void) createState:(NSString*) name nickName:(NSString*) nName licenseURL:(NSString*) url color:(UIColor*) color;

@end
```

and here is the stateObject.m file info:

@synthesize stateName,nickName,licensePlateURL,bkgColor;

```
-(void) createState:(NSString *)name nickName:(NSString *)nName licenseURL:(NSString *)url color:(UIColor *)color
{
    stateName = name;
    nickName = nName;
    licensePlateURL = url;
    bkgColor = color;

}
```

The object is set up in my dataSource class and added to my NSMutableArray, the object looks like this:

```
stateObject *newState1 = [[stateObject alloc] init];
[newState1 createState:@"Alabama" nickName:@"Yellowhammer State" licenseURL:@"http://www.15q.net/us1/al09a.jpg" color:[UIColor whiteColor]];
alabama = newState1;
```

The method I am using is this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//This line is now correct and properly sets the backgroundColor.
    cell.backgroundColor = [self.stateArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]bkgColor];
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
assignment2[11591:c07] -[stateObject color]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759b620
assignment2[11591:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[stateObject color]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759b620'
```

If I just create a UIColor object in said method and then set the value to that object, it works fine, so what am I doing wrong?

The whole reason I need to use the UIColor from the array is so the cells will retain their color even after I scroll them off the screen. They do not do so if I just set the color in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that your stateObject can't respond to the message "color". In other words your class stateObject do not have a method named "color".

Comment: But it does, I have edited the post above with the stateObject.h info.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your post, you made me go back and look at my code and realized I should have been using the bkgColor as my variable when setting the cell.backgroundColor so I will accept your answer as the correct one since it lead me to the correction.